# trace who sets a variable 'yas-snippet-dirs' in elisp

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

Some elisp init function sets the variable 'yas-snippet-dirs' incorrectly.

Is there a way to have a debug mode, to get a log of all the stacktraces which end up modifying this value ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a grep of the source code would take 2 seconds and give you all references to `yas-snippet-dirs`.  From there, you can go in and modify anything you don't like or create new functions or use advice, etc.  There's really no need, in my opinion, for a debug mode or stacktraces to handle what grep can do in a blink of an eye.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did `grep -r -n "yas-snippet-dirs" *` . But since those variables change are in call back in "code as data" style, I can't just put a break point in it or at least so was I thinking..

Comment: None of these references are built into the C code base.  They are all flat text files written in Lisp that end with the extension `.el`.  It's fairly straight forward to go in and modify them directly and then `M-x byte-compile-file` when you are done.  If you want to change something without modifying the source, then you just `(require ...)` the library in your `.emacs` file and underneath put the revised function with the same name.  No advanced debug/gdb skills are needed.  Perhaps you have just partial installation of Emacs without the source code Lisp files ending in `.el`?

Comment: Or, perhaps all your Lisp source code files are `.gz` compressed and your search is skipping over them.  After building Emacs, the last step I perform is a recursive **gunzip -k -f -r** for the express purpose of being able to **grep** the `.el` files when the need arises.  In your case, perhaps the installed third-party Lisp libraries have also been compressed and are beyond a basic grep?  If so, just **gunzip** them.

Comment: no, I can grep fine, but I mean the code appear in a data structure which has   `(use-package yasnippet
    :commands (yas-global-mode yas-minor-mode)
    :init
    (progn
 ....   (push 'yas-installed-snippets-dir yas-snippet-dirs)
...` so it's not a function I know put a breakpoint in or at least I would not know. it's code as data. its interpretation is triggered by the code being interpreted later on

Comment: As I understand it, your question essentially relates to using the library `use-package`.  Here are some related threads that may help:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/setq-yas-snippet-dirs-not-working | http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/stop-yasnippet-from-autoloading | http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18897/2287

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing, but you may find the [elisp bug hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter) useful.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent enough Emacs, you can use `debug-watch` for that:

```
M-x debug-watch RET yas-snippet-dirs RET
```

should do the trick.  If you need to add the watcher early on (before you can enter interactive commands), then put

```
(debug-watch 'yas-snippet-dirs)
```

somewhere early in your `~/.emacs`.